# A fundamental matter : Why do trigonometric function depend on unit?

Tags: trigonometry, angle, unit-of-measure

I may be confused with the wording here, and maybe my question has no reason to be - but in any case I am intrigued.

So like many people I work with angle and distances every day, and compute formulas using those, and use computers to calculate numerical results.

And I noticed that the computer is sensitive to the angle unit used, but not to any other units : feeding feet instead of meters (without telling the computer) will still get me a correct result (albeit in feet). Even if the formula makes use of many other units (seconds, degrees celsius, ... ) and I change all those units (to minutes, degrees kelvin, ...) the result that comes out is still correct (albeit in a different unit). Except if I feed radians instead of degrees.

But of course that doesn't happen for distances. Why ? Why are formulas containing sine and cosine dependent on the angle unit used, and not on any other unit used ?

Comment: The program you're using to calculate the trig functions simply expects radians (which is not a unit btw, just numbers.. a trig function don't know how to handle units.. e.g., what is $\cos(3 km)$? It doesn't make sense.)

Comment: That must be the fundamental difference I'm looking for. Angles are constants with no units. That's why sin(angle in radians) makes sense (turning a constant in another constant) but sin(distance in km) doesn't.

Comment: But ... why are angle constants with no unit ? Don't they represent something measurable just like anything else ?

Comment: @Charles - Angles measure the ratio of arc length to radius. Being a ratio of distances, it is unitless. I admit that it does feel strange (to me at least) for them not to have a unit though.

Comment: @Lovsovs Angles *do* have units, clearly, otherwise we wouldn’t have this question in the first place. They are, however, *dimensionless*, which is not the same thing.

Comment: @amd Didn't know that those terms where not used synonymously - how can a dimensionless thing not also always be unitless?

Comment: @Lovsovs This is a somewhat different sense of “dimension” than in geometry and linear algebra. In the context of physics and dimensional analysis, dimensions are things like length, time, mass and charge. Length can be measured in meters, feet, furlongs, light-years, and so on, but those are all still lengths. Angles have no dimension in this sense, but they are still measured relative to some unit—radian, degree, or grad. See [Myridium’s answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1987306/265466), below.

Answer (score 2):

This confusion arises because angles are *dimensionless*. Let's first look at the case of computing the area of a circle in terms of its radius:

$$A = \pi r^2$$

When we plug in a value for $r$ with units, we get back an answer with units:

$$ \pi (3\, \mathrm m)^2 = (9 \pi) \, \mathrm m^2$$

We could have started with any unit, and we will get back an answer which is expressed in units.

However, when we use the trigonometric functions, we plug in something *dimensionless* and get back something dimensionless:

$$\sin (\pi \; \text{radians}) = 0 \quad , \quad \sin (180^\circ) = 0$$
The input to the $\sin$ function is a pure (*real*) number without any units attached to it. The expression $180^\circ$ only means something to the humans who read it. We see $180^\circ$ and interpret that degree sign $\circ$ to be a constant factor of $\pi / 180$ multiplying the number preceding it. By converting the argument to $\sin$ to radians, the $\sin$ function can be *defined* so that it looks like this:

[image]

**Instead** of looking like this (function of degrees):

[image]

In principle, we could use either definition. If we chose the latter, then we should convert arguments in radians to their value in degrees. However, there are **good reasons** for choosing the former definition which takes in *radians* as the input. One of the best illustrations of these 'good reasons' is that $\mathrm d \sin(x) / \mathrm d x = \cos x$. If we chose the latter definition, then instead it would be $\mathrm d \sin(x) / \mathrm d x = \frac \pi {180} \cos x$.

In mathematics, if the $\circ$ sign is not used, then it is assumed that the argument is measured in radians. In other words, we take $\sin$ to be first definition above. It is not good practice to implement a `sin` function in a program which expects degrees, because this goes against convention. I would advise naming such a function something like `sind` instead.

Comment: Would you mind adding your images directly ? imgur is not accessible from my work.

Comment: @Charles: Imgur _is_ where all the StackExchange sites host user-uploaded images.

Comment: Ow. Yeah the name _was_ stack.imgur. Erm, then I don't know ...

Comment: @Charles - Temporary links: [First](http://puu.sh/rXcEd/33704a7613.png) and [Second](http://puu.sh/rXcEX/d5fbd32393.png)

Comment: @Myridium Haha thanks but any website remotely looking like file storage will get blocked. Will check it out from home. But your explanation is still very helpful. Question now is wording : I remember the old differenciation we made during my studies between _dimension_ and _unit_. Can we say degrees have various possible units but never any dimension ?

Comment: @Charles - I'm not sure of the differences between those words in this context. I interchange them in this circumstance, but correct me if I'm wrong. In physics at least, we would say that the units *meters* and *kilometers* both have *dimensions* of $L$ which stands for "length".

Comment: @Myridum Yes that's how it was for me too. And T for time etc ... and nothing for angles. Even though you can specify degrees or radians or gradians.

Comment: @Charles - Degrees, radians and gradians are different *units* I think, but they are all *dimensionless*. Degrees = $\pi/180$, gradians = $\pi/200$, and radians = $1$. They are different units I suppose, but they all have the dimension of a pure number, which we call *dimensionless*.

Comment: @Charles Almost right. *Angles* have no dimension, but they do have units, one of which is called the “degree.”

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, for example, that you add two distances. 10 meters plus 5 meters make 15 meters, of course. And 10 feet plus 5 feet make 15 feet. But 10 meters plus 5 meters is not the same distance as 10 feet plus 5 feet -- how does $10+5$ know the difference? The naked addition doesn't, but since you get another distance *out* of the addition, it is reasonable that the $15$ you get out should be interpreted in the same units as the distances you put in -- that that is what can make the same addition produce a number $15$ that means two different actual lengths in the two cases.

When you take a sine, however, you put an angle in, and get a dimensionless ratio out. (The result of a sine can be interpreted as a ratio of two distances, and the *ratio* is the same number no matter which units you measure those distances in).

Since the result of $\sin(2)$ does not have any units attached to it, it is *impossible from the outset* to use the units of the result to interpret the same sine operation to give the right result no matter whether we meant 2 *degrees* or 2 *radians*.

Instead, the sine computation needs to know which units its input was measured by.